# Infinite Recursion after specifying Object Mappers

Tags: java, spring, rest

An infinite recursion error occurs after adding the following code to a `SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` subclass:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper halObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

The error is:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 

    threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
     org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not
     write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]-
    >org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.CachingMongoPersistentProperty["owner"]->
```

This happens when performing a GET on a spring mongo repository. If I remove the `halObjectMapper()` line, it works. However, I need to have this defined. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are the two mappers working for the same classes? I mean are they mapping the same packages ?

Comment: @engma yeah they are, I think